# fopen("filename", "wb") returns null

Tags: c++, macos, g++, fopen

Code like this:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main(){
    FILE* to = NULL; 
    to = fopen("cpp", "wb");
    if(to != NULL)
        cout << 1 << endl ;
    cout << 2 << endl;
}
```

compile with `g++` with option `-o`,then run.Returns "2".To see cpp folder with `ls -al` :`drwxr-xr-x   2 anyone  staff    64  6  8 08:31 cpp`

Why it returns "2".Why I cannot open the folder for write?

Comment: You do not want to fopen a directory. fopen is for file.  I think you can open a directory as a file, but you do not want to do it. The permissions are about adding files to the director and listing the directory contents. Sorry, do not know which functions you should be using.

Comment: why do you think you should be able to open folder for writing using function that open files?

Comment: What are you _actually_  trying to do? Writing to a folder doesn't really make sense. Read this: [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info)

Comment: @Jabberwocky Because I'm trying to use aidl-cpp commandline to generate cpp file which implement the aidl interface.but I can only generate the header file,the source file cannot be generated because the folder out put cannot be open.I check the aidl-cpp source code,there is a line code like this `fopen("cpp", "wb");`,because this line return null,the aidl-cpp commandline throw error and exit.So I'm trying to make fopen return not null.

Comment: If `cpp` is a _directory_, then opening it with `fopen` doesn't make sense. It's as simple as that.

Comment: @WilliamJBagshaw I get what you mean.fopen cannot open a directory.just can open a file.That's it?

Comment: @Eilir _fopen cannot open a directory. It just can open a file_: yes, that's what everybody is trying to tell you.

Comment: @Jabberwocky  I did a mistake.Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because you are trying to open a folder for writing. According to [`fopen` documentation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/fopen.html), you get `[EISDIR]` error:

> `[EISDIR]`
>   
> The named file is a directory and mode requires write access.

You can tell what error you get by printing `strerror(errno))`:

```
cout << strerror(errno)) << endl;
```

Comment: I got `Is a directory`.

Comment: @Eilir Right, that's a totally expected outcome. You cannot open directory for writing with `fopen`, because there are no folder operations available to you that would make sense within the file system API.

Answer (score 1):

fopen is for opening files and not folders, are you sure cpp is a folder or did you do a mistake ?

Comment: I did a mistake.Sorry.